# brightcove video not working for IE8 in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, brightcove

I'm trying to embed a video but it's not working for IE8. I managed to isolate it and I can confirm the problem happens only on a wordpress site, when I enter the embed code in the post edit page.

this is my code:

```
// in the header
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/APIModules_all.js"></script>

//in the post
<div class="video-container"><object id="snippet7" class="BrightcoveExperience">
          <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
          <param name="width" value="540px" />
          <param name="height" value="310px" />
          <param name="playerID" value="61385794001" />

          <param name="publisherID" value="58740635001"/>

          <param name="isVid" value="true" />
          <param name="isUI" value="true" />
          <param name="@videoPlayer" value="1328442650001" />
          <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
          <param name="autoStart" value="false" />
        </object>   
</div>
```

you can see a live example here:
http://www.theisraelcourse.com/wordpress/?page_id=81

with every browser it's working, except IE8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Wordpress themes apply `max-width:100%` to `object` which makes IE8 to collapse the player to 0 height. You can override that for the player object:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .BrightcoveExperience { max-width: none }
</style>
```